# Proving a function is continuous given another function is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

[image]

Hello, everyone, I am (still) stuck on this question.  The problem, I am having in proving continuity is knowing which definition of continuity is best to use to prove the statement.

I know three definitions of continuity: 
[image]

I was thinking of using the second definition for this question.  I know pre-images of open sets in $R$ are open in [0,1] x [0,1] as f  is continuous.  Now, I think I have to somehow use this fact to show that the pre-images of open sets on [0,1], $g^-1(A)$ are open.  I'm not sure if this is the right technique or if my thinking is even right or if it is completely misguided.  I could really use help, guidance, and some explanation for the question.  Thanks!!

Note, I only know these three definitions of continuity and I know nothing about compactness as we have not covered that yet.

Comment: Haven't you asked the exact same question yesterday? What happened to that?

Comment: If you know nothing about compactness, how do you know the maximum exists?

Comment: That question was different.  This question deals with maximum and rectangle.  I'm not sure, as we haven't covered compactness.

Comment: Is there a way to do this using open balls?

Comment: If there is an alternate way, (using perhaps), could someone give me hints on how to proceed with the proof, thanks!!